# Multi-column table layout the right way

Tags: output-formatting

How do I create book-like multi-column table formatting for a long, narrow tables in a preferably elegant way? Should I be thinking of stylesheets, instead of formatting? I guess this is a solved problem, after all.

Row expression below is my own, feeble attempt to solve the problem. Although output is reasonably OK, I detest many details on the implementation; for instance, the magic constant 1.2 needed to make columns evenly tall.

```
Row[Pane[
      Grid[#, Frame -> All, ItemSize -> {Automatic, 1.2}, 
       ItemStyle -> FontFamily -> "Times", 
       Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Center}],
      ImageMargins -> 2] &
    /@ Partition[#1, #2]] &[
 {Round[#[[1]]], CityData[#[[2]], "FullName"]} &
  /@ ({GeoDistance[$GeoLocation, CityData[#, "Coordinates"]]/
        1000, #} & 
     /@ CityData[]~Select~(CityData[#, "Population"] >= 100000 &))
   ~SortBy~First
   ~Take~(3*20),
 20]
```

[image: OPs code]

Comment: It is unclear what is detestable in the users own output. The "magic constant" 1.2 is simply the vertical item size -- not magic or a fudge factor or anything like that, just a standard way to size row heights. Some aesthetic changes could be made depending on personal preferences but the user has not indicated what these could be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps I am missing the subtlety of your formatting needs but I think you can make this a lot simpler.

With your two column table as `dat` try:

```
Grid[
  dat ~Partition~ 20 ~Flatten~ {{2}, {1, 3}},
  Dividers -> {{All, {3 -> Thick, 5 -> Thick}}, All},
  Alignment -> {{{Right, Left}}, Center},
  Spacings -> {{{1, 0.5}}},
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times"}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If the separation between pairs of columns is desired you might use:

```
Row[
 Grid[#,
    Dividers -> All,
    Alignment -> {{Right, Left}},
    Spacings -> {{{1, 0.5}}},
    BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times"}
 ] & /@
  dat ~Partition~ 20
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

#### Third try:

```
newdat = Flatten @ Riffle[#, Item[Spacer[0], Frame -> {False, True, False, True}]] & /@ 
          Transpose[dat ~Partition~ 20];

Grid[
  newdat,
  Dividers -> All,
  Alignment -> {{{Right, Left}}, Center},
  Spacings -> {{{1, 0.5, 0.5}}},
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times"}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is the inverse of the above (output looks the same); it may be more convenient sometimes.

```
newdat = Flatten @ Riffle[#, Spacer[0]] & /@ 
   Transpose[Map[Item[#, Frame -> All] &, dat, {2}] ~Partition~ 20];

Grid[
  newdat,
  Alignment -> {{{Right, Left}}, Center},
  Spacings -> {{{1, 0.5, 0.5}}},
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times"}
]
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm wondering if something is missing from your separated example, since it renders without separation in my case. I can see what you're trying to do. The problem here is that while first one keeps lines aligned, there's no separation, and while second one has separation, it actually results unaesthetically unaligned columns when contents contain accented text. Getting rid of both of these is awkward or kludgy...

Comment: @kirma try `Row[ ...content..dat ~Partition~ 20, Spacer[5]]`

Comment: @kirma with accented text you are introducing a different line height. That is why the "magic constant" is useful.

Comment: @kirma what do you mean by *accented text*?

Comment: @kirma I added a third example; please tell me if this is any better.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yes, the issue was with accented text. Your third example has the essence. I achieved the same with much more complicated construct; Frame logic has something that's highly unintuitive to me, but now there's a reasonable example how to do it. :)

Comment: @kirma Glad I finally found something that helped, and thanks for the Accept.  I slightly refined the code for the last method, and posted a variation that is essentially the inverse (`Frame` on the text elements rather than the spacers).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard How would one go about changing the colour of the lines?

Comment: @wxffles you can specify color directives for the `Dividers` option, e.g. `Dividers -> Red` or `Dividers -> {Red, Blue}`.  Likewise for `Frame` but either `Frame -> (*color for all*)` or `Frame -> {bottom, left, top, right}`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks.  It appears it is as easy as I thought it should have been.  But if you put one extraneous set of braces in, you can get lost and confused.

Comment: @wxffles That's true; the specification for `Dividers` is one of the most complicated I've seen in *Mathematica*.  It does however let you do advanced things such as this: `Dividers -> {{Green, {Red, Blue}, Gray, Pink}, {{{Thick, Thin}}, 
   4 -> Directive[Thick, Green]}}` but I admit getting the `{}` right is a headache.